# IE11 / Edge buggy box-shadow rendering

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rendering, microsoft-edge, box-shadow

```
<style>
#a > span {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 3px red;
}
#a > span:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 3px blue;
}
#a > span + span {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
</style>
<div id="a"><span>AAAA</span><span>BBBB</span><span>CCCC</span></div>
```

The desired output should be that box-shadow blue overlays box-shadow red. FF does it, Chrome and even Safari. But IE11 and Edge give me these nice hover-effects:

[image][image]

Am I missing something? Or is MS rendering that bad? Any suggestions how to get a blury box-shadow instead, cross browser solution?

(In my real code I even got trembling! box-shadows caused by rotating elements with opacity 0.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is inline necessary for you? If it is not, adding display: inline-block to your first rule should fix this in IE.

```
#a > span {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 3px red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You are right! I didn't think of that. Maybe as a general rule you should use inline-**block** when fiddling with the style of the **box**. Thanks, saved me a lot of trouble

Comment: IE does not accept opacity on color of box-shadow like 
box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 0px #4F5D5B66